# Kivy: Can't update text input value from another class

Tags: python, kivy, textinput

I'm new on `kivy`.I'm trying to change text input value (the string value that is shown in `TextInput` box) from another class, But nothing passes.

I have following widgets in `class MyFirstScreen`:

- One `RecycleView` with multiple items (each item is a `dictionary`)
- Two `TextInput`s

**What I want to do:** When each items in `RecycleView` selected, `TextInput`s should be update and load with corresponding values of selected item's `dictionary`.

But when i try to access current `TextInput`'s value from another class (`class SelectableLabel`):

```
class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    #...
    def update_text_inputs(self, *kwarg):
        my_text_input = MyFirstScreen().ids.system_name_text_input_id #<--i can access to widget
        print("my_print_val is:", my_text_input.text) #<--but widget's current text value is : ''
        my_text_input.text = "Updated Value"
```

I can access to `my_text_input` widget but its text (`my_text_input.text`) is an empty string (`''`).Furthermore when i change the value of `my_text_input.text`, nothing happens in `TextInput`'s box.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here or how to make this work? Thank you in advance...

**Here is my .py code:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior


class Manager(ScreenManager):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class MyFirstScreen(Screen):
    system_name_text_input_id = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwarg):
        super().__init__(**kwarg)
        print("__init__ of MyFirstScreen is Called")

    def get_text_inputs(self):
        ret_val = self.ids.system_name_text_input_id.text
        print("get_text_input is called, ret_val:", ret_val)
        return ret_val


class RecycleViewWidget(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RecycleViewWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.items_of_rv = []
        for i in range(1, 21):
            self.items_of_rv.append(
                {"color": (0, 0, 0, 1), "font_size": "20", "text": f"User {i}",
                 "user_id": f"{100 * i}"})
        self.data = [item for item in self.items_of_rv]


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior, RecycleBoxLayout):
    """ Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. """


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    """ Add selection support to the Label """
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        """ Catch and handle the view changes """
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        """ Add selection on touch down """
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        """ Respond to the selection of items in the view. """

        self.selected = not is_selected
        if is_selected:
            rv.data[index].update({'color': (1, 1, 1, 1)})
            self.refresh_view_attrs(RecycleViewWidget(), index, rv.data[index])
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
            self.update_text_inputs()
        else:
            if rv.data[index].get("color") == (1, 1, 1, 1):
                rv.data[index].update({'color': (0, 0, 0, 1)})
                self.refresh_view_attrs(RecycleViewWidget(), index, rv.data[index])
        self.selected = not self.selected

    def update_text_inputs(self, *kwarg):
        my_text_input = MyFirstScreen().ids.system_name_text_input_id#<--i can access to widget
        print("my_print_val is:", my_text_input.text)#<--but widget's current text value is : ''
        # my_text_input.text = "Updated Value" 

main_style = Builder.load_file("test.kv")


class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return main_style


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**And my .kv code:**

```
Manager:
    MyFirstScreen:

<SelectableLabel>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0, 1, 1) if self.selected else (1, 1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<RecycleViewWidget>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'

<MyFirstScreen>:
    name: 'system_setup_page'
    system_name_text_input_id:system_name_text_input_id
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        BoxLayout:
            cols: 1
            padding: 20
            RecycleViewWidget:
        FloatLayout:
            Label:
                size_hint: None, None
                text: "Name:"
                font_size: 22
                pos_hint: {'center': (20/100, 90/100)}
            TextInput:
                id: system_name_text_input_id
                size_hint: None, None
                hint_text: "Type Your Name..."
                size: 200, 30
                multiline: False
                pos_hint: {'center': (65/100, 90/100)}
                on_text: root.get_text_inputs()
            Label:
                size_hint: None, None
                text: "User ID:"
                font_size: 20
                pos_hint: {'center': (20/100, 70/100)}
            TextInput:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 30
                hint_text: "Type Your ID..."
                pos_hint: {'center': (65/100, 70/100)}
```

Comment: probably using `MyFirstScreen()` you create second instance of class `MyFirstScreen` and you read text from second instance instead of access original first instance. And when you run `update_text_inputs` again then you create third (fourth, fifth, etc) instance of class `MyFirstScreen` instead of using first instance. But only first instance may have text which you put in `TextInput`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is because using `MyFirstScreen()` in `update_text_inputs()` you create new instance of class `MyFirstScreen` but you have to use existing instance.

It should be better way to get it but at this moment my only idea is to use `parent` for this .

Because there are many widgets between these elements so it needs many `parent`:

```
    my_text_input = self.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.system_name_text_input_id
```

I found it using `print(self.parent)`, next `print(self.parent.parent)`, etc.

---

```
def update_text_inputs(self, *kwarg):
    #print('parent:', self.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.system_name_text_input_id)
    #print('parent:', self.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.system_name_text_input_id.text)

    my_text_input = self.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.system_name_text_input_id 

    print("my_print_val is:", my_text_input.text)

    my_text_input.text = "Updated Value"
```

Comment: BTW: if you move `system_name_text_input_id:system_name_text_input_id` to `RecycleViewWidget:` (not `<RecycleViewWidget>`) then you will  need less `parent`s.

Comment: Dear furas, Thank you again for your help. This problem was solved, But i found new problem with your suggested solution. There is an error in this situation:
1.If i select an item (for example : "User 1") ->TextInputs Values load properly.
2. Then i scroll DOWN until the selected item hides completely from `RecycleView`.
3. I scroll UP to show selected item again.
Immediately when I want to do step 3, this error occur:
`my_text_input=
self.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.system_name_text_input_id
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'`
What's the problem?

Comment: I would have to run code to understand problem. Create new question on new page - you will have more space to put full code, full error message and describe problem. And new people will see it - so maybe someone will find better solution.

Comment: My code has no change. Just new error occurred.
However, if creating a new question is needed, I will do it.

Comment: Here is my new question: [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent' when scroll down and scroll up again in recycle view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61924388/kivy-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-parent-when-scroll-do?noredirect=1#comment109525895_61924388)